# Move a file to amazon via cygwin

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, cygwin

I'm trying to push a file from my local windows machine to an amazon server into the folder /var/www

```
rsync  -e 'ssh -i /cygdrive/d/myaws.pem' /cygdrive/d/web/my_site.jpa ubuntu@176.69.69.9/var/www
```

Unsuccessful with this error

rsync: change_dir#3 "/home/mark//ubuntu@176.34.50.7/var" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: What happens when you do "ssh -i /cygdrive/d/myaws.pem ubuntu@176.69.69.9"? Do you have some sort of startup script that may be involved with the other IP shown in the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a colon here:

```
ubuntu@176.69.69.9/var/www
```

should be

```
ubuntu@176.69.69.9:/var/www
```